# Android-Threading: refer to Views from Threads

Tags: android, multithreading, performance, user-interface, listview

I've tried to use threads for better performance in my Android App.
In the `onCreate` Method i started two threads:

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.play);

    ...

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
         makeList();
        }
    }).start();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
         setChronometer();
        }
    }).start();  
}
```

In these Methods I change the some settings of my Views. (no heavy events)

First a Chronometer:

```
 private void setChronometer(){
 time.post(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
       time.setFormat("Time: %s");
       time.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
       time.start();
         }
       });
 }
```

Second a `ListView`:

```
private void makeList(){
  ...
        final ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(...);  

        list.post(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
          list.setAdapter(listAdapter); 
          list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,  View view, int position, long id) {
    ....

         }
       });
 }
```

The `Chronometer` works fine, 
but the operations in `makeList()` weren't done.. so my ListView isn't working!

I had the idea,that when the activity starts, defining the listView and Chronometer is less important, so i defer them in threads, with the aim, that the activity starts faster (is more performat)

First of all, was this a good Idea?

Secondly, why is my ListView not working? When i remove the `list.post(new Runnable() {`
it works, but i thought that wasn't a good way in android. Cause now the Views are directy changed from a thread.

Thirdly, when should i use Threads `vs.View.post`?

Any help would be great, Thanks!

Greetings
FireDragon

Comment: Please don't use backticks (`) in your text but (') as the backtick has a special meaning in markdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to remember is that the elements of your UI - your `View`s and `ListView`s etc - must only ever be accessed by your UI thread (i.e. your main thread). If you want to modify your UI from a background thread, you need to instantiate a `Handler` (on your UI thread) and send it messages and/or runnables from your background thread.

Sounds a bit messy? Fortunately Android includes a very powerful class called [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) which is *exactly* what you need to get busy learning. You put your background thread code in it's `doInBackground()` member, and you do your UI updating in `onPostExecute()`, and it's oh-so-much simpler than fiddling around with `new Thread()` and `Handler`s etc.

Comment: Although I should say, the code you pasted doesn't show anything that *needs* to go on a background thread. Setting adapters etc is all just UI init and should stay on your UI thread. Loading data from storage, or over the network, however - any kind of slow I/O - *that's* what you need to do in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Reuben is right about AsyncTask.  However, if you want to understand how Threading works I've detailed the [various approaches on blog](http://blog.bsodmike.com/2010/12/26/android-multithreading-in-a-ui-environment/).  AsyncTask is the way to go though.